# VMware vCenter cannot connect to ESXi Hosts

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

I have a mixed version ESXi environment with versions 4.1, 5.0 and 5.5 hosts. I also have a standalone server, running Windows Server 2012 R2 that has vCenter 5.5 installed on it.

All these servers are on the same subnet of 192.168.10.x and have the same gateway, which is a Cisco ASA5505 firewall. Everything is then connected into a Cisco 2960G switch.

The problem I am having is adding servers to the vCenter, getting the following error:

```
Call "Datacenter.QueryConnectionInfo" for object "Nuco" on vCenter Server "vsphere" failed.
```

If I try to connect directly to the host from this server, I get the same issue, it refuses to connect. I can then go to my PC (connected remotely over VPN) and connect just fine.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Any error on esxi host log?

Comment: What's the best way to get to the logs? Whe I looked via SSH, I couldnt see anything in particular.

Comment: Can you ping the ESXi host from the vCenter server?

Comment: Yes, I could ping them all. Solved the problem now. It was the fact that the Cisco ASA had proxy-arp enabled on the inside interface and giving out error messages about conflicting IPs.